# Why does a MediaController affect hiding the Navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My app consists of a ViewPager that displays images and videos. The app should go into immersive view on a tap, and come out of immersive view on a tap of after 3 seconds. I also want the status bar to always be hidden. This mostly works, however...

I'm using a variation of the SystemUIHider classes that are generated in Android Studio.  I've created a new class called SystemUIHiderKitKat which uses these flags. 
Clicking on the screen will show the navigation and actionbar (not the status bar). Clicking within 3 seconds will hide the navigation and status bar. And waiting more than 3 seconds will automatically hide the navigation and actions bars.

Video of the bars functioning as expected, but without the MediaController : [Working](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6naYuAKJVSHbkFtN2pNa1AzalU/edit?usp=sharing)

Video of bars not working correctly when MediaController is toggled : [Not Working](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6naYuAKJVSHanR1VjRLNnU4ZEU/edit?usp=sharing)

```
  mShowFlags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;

  mHideFlags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;

  mTestForHiddenFlags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
```

My VideoView and MediaController are both members of a custom FrameLayout class

```
public class MyVideoView extends FrameLayout 
{
  setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
  {
     @Override
     public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
     {
        final int hidden = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        if ((hidden & visibility) != 0) {
           m_mediaController.hide();                  //   A
        }
        else {
           m_mediaController.show();              //    B
        }
     }
  });
```

If I comment out lines A and B everything works perfectly (the "working" video). If lines A and B are not commented out, then when I click the Action Bar does hide, but the navigation bar does not(the "Not Working" video). In a second or two the delayedHide(int delayMillis) method gets call and then the navigation bar does hide (!!).  Now, this baffles me because calls the same hide() method and mAnchorView.setSystemUiVisibility(mHideFlags) is called with the same flags value as the first call (obviously)

Comment: I think the problem is the media controller places a new window on top of yours. This stops you from hiding the system ui until the window is removed. May need to copy source and make some changes. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/MediaController.java

Comment: Why would that stop me from hiding the UI? Because actually, half of the UI is hidden. The action bar goes away, the navigation bar doesn't. ﻿

Comment: Because the media controller places another window on top of the one tied to your flags. Therefore when its window is on top the system ui flags you set are not active.

Comment: @MikeWallaceDev what you end up doing eventually?